# CodeIgniter is printing unspecified currency(¤) when POST Form data is processed

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome

I am not able to remove unspecified currency symbol(¤) when I am printing string to browser in CodeIgniter. I have already sanitized POST data and when I see html code via ctrl+u for chrome then its vanish out. Please help me to remove this.

**Below is output on browser**

language=EN&amount=100¤cy=USD&redirect_url=abc.com

```
 $data='';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                     
                     $data.=$key.'='.$value.'&';
                    }
 echo $data;
```

Dump of $_POST is as below and in dump, currency symbol is not visible.

```
array(14) {
    ["country"]=> string(3) "INR" 
    ["language"]=> string(2) "EN" 
    ["amount"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
    ["billing_name"]=> string(4) "ABCD" 
    ["billing_email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" 
    ["billing_tel"]=> string(10) "9876543210" 
    ["billing_address"]=> string(12) "Delhi, India" 
    ["billing_city"]=> string(5) "Delhi" 
    ["billing_state"]=> string(5) "delhi" 
    ["billing_zip"]=> string(6) "110001" 
    ["billing_country"]=> string(5) "India"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump($_POST) prior to your foreach? How are you sanitizing $_POST?

Comment: Dump of $_POST is as below  and in dump currency symbol is not visible . array(14) { ["country"]=> string(3) "INR" ["language"]=> string(2) "EN" ["amount"]=> string(3) "100" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD"  ["billing_name"]=> string(4) "ABCD" ["billing_email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" ["billing_tel"]=> string(10) "9876543210" ["billing_address"]=> string(12) "Delhi, India" ["billing_city"]=> string(5) "Delhi" ["billing_state"]=> string(5) "delhi" ["billing_zip"]=> string(6) "110001" ["billing_country"]=> string(5) "India" }

Answer (score 0):

So what you are seeing is this...

```
language=EN&amount=100¤cy=USD&redirect_url=abc.com
```

What you should be seeing is this...

```
language=EN&amount=100&currency=USD&redirect_url=abc.com
```

So the observed output is missing the **&curren** which is being replaced by the character you are seeing.

The work around for this is to use htmlentities, to prevent this translation.

So your code will become

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $data .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$data = trim($data, '&'); // hack to remove last &
echo htmlentities($data); // This will give the correct result
```

> FYI ( From wikipedia ) The Currency sign is represented in Unicode as
> U+00A4 ¤
> CURRENCY SIGN (HTML &#164 ; · &curren ;) ***added space before each ;
> to let it display*